# Función retorna null y no evalúa la condición declarada

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

La función debe retornar 0 en el caso de que comisión sea `null`, el problema es que me sigue mostrando `null` aunque le ponga la condición.

```
create or replace function fn_total_com 
(f_id vendedor.id_vendedor%type)
return number is
  cursor cur_empleados is
    select 
      nvl2(sum(valor_comision_boleta),
      sum(valor_comision_boleta),0) com
      from vendedor natural left join   boleta natural left join  comision_ventas 
      where to_char(fecha_boleta,'mm')=5 and id_vendedor=f_id
      group by id_vendedor;
      reg_emp cur_empleados%rowtype;
      v_total number(10);
        begin
          for reg_emp in cur_empleados
            loop
              if reg_emp.com is not null then
                  v_total:=reg_emp.com;
              else
                  v_total := 0;
              end if;
            end loop;
      return v_total;
end;


select id_vendedor,fn_total_com(id_vendedor) fff 
  from comision_ventas
  join boleta using (nro_boleta)
 group by id_vendedor,
          fn_total_com(id_vendedor);
```

Comment: Deberías verificar está porción de tu consulta: `where to_char(fecha_boleta,'mm')=5` estas comparando char con number.

Answer (score 0):

El cursor no está retornando datos, esa es la razón que encuentro del porqué no te funciona. El loop no se ejecutó y por ende no se evalúa la condición.

Prueba con esto:

```
create or replace function fn_total_com 
    (f_id vendedor.id_vendedor%type)
return number is

  cursor cur_empleados is

    select 
      nvl2(sum(valor_comision_boleta),
      sum(valor_comision_boleta),0) com
      from vendedor 
      natural left join   boleta 
      natural left join  comision_ventas 
      where to_char(fecha_boleta,'mm')=5 and id_vendedor=f_id
      group by id_vendedor;

      reg_emp cur_empleados%rowtype;
      v_total number(10);

begin

      for reg_emp in cur_empleados
        loop
          v_total := nvl(reg_emp.com, 0);
        end loop;

      return nvl(v_total, 0);
end;
```